# How to avoid statement duplication in where clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Is there any way to use an alias as a substitute of a single result query in `WHERE` clause to avoid statement duplication in the following query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM SomeTable T 
    WHERE created <= (CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT created 
        FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE sales > 0 
        ORDER BY created DESC 
        LIMIT 1)
    IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE 
    (SELECT created 
        FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE sales > 0 
        ORDER BY created DESC 
        LIMIT 1)
    END)
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10
) as inverseOrder
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

Is it possible to modify that query to avoid the statement duplication. I.e. something like that?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM SomeTable T 
    WHERE created <= someAliasssssssss
    IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE someAliasssssssss
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10
) as inverseOrder
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM SomeTable T 
    WHERE created <= COALESCE(
        (SELECT created 
        FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE sales > 0 
        ORDER BY created DESC 
        LIMIT 1), NOW())
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10
) as inverseOrder
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed!